# mysql Insert from left join where field match

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert values from table2 to table1 where addressB matches addressA. My attempt so far is the code below. The query seems to insert new blank records to the table1 instead what I want it to do. Can someone please tell me if this query is correct?

```
INSERT INTO database1.table1 (name)
select database2.table2.distName
from database2.table2
left join database1.table1
On database2.table2.addressB = database1.table1.addressA
where database2.table2.addressB = database1.table1.addressA
```

My sql fiddle

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aca3e/2
```

Comment: I do not really understand what you would like to achieve! 1. There is no point in using a left join and then repeat the join condition in where as well. Use an inner join instead. 2. If the address already exists in table1, then why do you insert a record instead of updating it? 3. Are you sure that `a_distName2` field is populated in table2?

Comment: I repeated the where condition as the join was not giving the correct result. I get the exact results I want when I use only the select part of the query. Yes distName field exists in table2

Comment: If the select part alone produces the expected outcome, then the problem is with the insert part, but we would have to see the target table structure and some sample data from both tables.

Comment: I will create sql fiddle example

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aca3e/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the sql fiddle I'm even more convinced that you need to use `update` and not insert.

```
update table1 inner join table2 on table1.addressA=table2.addressB
set table1.distname=table2.distname
```

The null values in the table1.id columns after your insert are the result of lacking a primary key on table1.id and lacking of the auto_increment specification on the same column.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to understand my problem. I was mixing up insert for update. Your query works

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO database1.table1 (name)
select database2.table2.a_distName2
from database2.table2
left join database1.table1
On database2.table2.addressB = database1.table1.addressA
where database1.table1.addressA is null;
```

Comment: `where database1.table1.addressA is null;` can be avoid if you will use `inner join`

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO database1.table1 (name)
select database2.table2.a_distName2
from database2.table2
inner join database1.table1
On database2.table2.addressB = database1.table1.addressA
```